# XSLT Xpath Query

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<response>
  <propertySearchSales>                                                                           
     <properties rentalperiod="0"><pages page="1" count="153" pageCount="16" perPage="10">
        <pages page="1" count="153" pageCount="16" perPage="10">
          <page number="1" selected="true"/>
```

I'm trying to access the page number attribute value with the following xslt code:

```
<xsl:if test="//response//propertySearchSales//properties/pages/@number>1">
```

But it's not working, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Your sample XML has a `pages` element nested within a `pages`element - is that correct? It would explain why your XPath can't find the `page` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to access the page number attribute value with the
>   following xslt code:
>
> ```
> <xsl:if test="//response//propertySearchSales//properties/pages/@number>1">
> ```

**An `xsl:if` instruction doesn't "access" any node** -- it determines if a condition is `true()` or `false()`

**An Xpath expression that *selects* nodes that satisfy a condition has the condition inside a *predicate*.**

Therefore, the above XPath expression needs to be modified to something like this:

```
(ExpressionSelectingNodes)[//response//propertySearchSales//properties/pages/@number>1]
```

**As other people have noticed, a `pages` element in the provided XML document doesn't have any `number` attribute**.

Therefore, most likely you need an expression like this:

```
(ExpressionSelectingNodes)[//response//propertySearchSales//properties/pages/page/@number>1]
```

**In case you need to select any `page`, whose `number` attribute's string value, treated as number, is greater than the number 1, use**:

```
//response//propertySearchSales//properties/pages/page/[@number>1]
```

**Finally, based on the provided XML document, the above expression can be optimized to:**

```
/response/propertySearchSales/properties/pages/page/[@number>1]
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation of `xsl:if` and a much more comprehensive answer than mine!

Comment: @MattJones, You are welcome. I should have also said that explicit XSLT conditionals such as `xsl:if` should be avoided in preference to template match patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/response/propertySearchSales/properties/pages/page[@number>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sample XML is correct, then your XPath is wrong due to the `pages` having a child element of `pages`.

For your supplied XML this should work:

```
<xsl:if test="//response/propertySearchSales/properties/pages/pages/page[@number>1]">
```

If the additional `pages` element is a mistake, try this:

```
<xsl:if test="//response/propertySearchSales/properties/pages/page[@number>1]">
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way is

```
<xsl:if test="//page[@number>1]">
```